# Issue with Cc and Bcc in sending mails using SMTP - PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm sending email from my php page using SMTP. everything works perfect except Bcc.

This is how I got my email, Interestingly I can see bcc as well.
[image]

Whats wrong in my code, can anyone please help.

```
$Headers = array("MIME-Version"=> '1.0', 
"Content-type" => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1",
"From" => $From,
"To" => $To, 
"Bcc" => $User_copy,
"Reply-To" => $From,
"Subject" => $Subject);

$SMTP = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $Host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $Username, 'password' => $Password)); 
$mail = $SMTP->send($To, $Headers, $Message);
```

Comment: Your mail server does not strip `Bcc:` headers.  How do you use $headers variable?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip I add 2 extra line at the bototm of my question. also check this example, i get help from that `http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Diagnose**:
Your mail server does not strip Bcc: headers.

**Fix:**
**Do not** specify bcc recipients in `BCC:` headers.
Add the bcc recipients to first parameter of `send`.

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php

Comment: I did that `$Recipients = $To.", ".$User_copy;` and now it send an email copy as Bcc to `$User_copy` but if I want to use Cc instead, then how I will mention that.

Comment: Silent `Bcc:` - add only to `$To`. Loud `Cc:` - add to `$To` *and* add `Cc:` header(s).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$To=(string)$SendToEmail ;
$bcc = "WEBMASTERS_EMAIL_ADDRESS";
$recipients = $To.",".$bcc;
$headers["From"] = "who@whatever";
$headers["To"] = $To;
$headers["Reply-To"] = $visitormail;
$headers["Subject"] = $subject;
$mailmsg = $message;
/* SMTP server name, port, user/passwd */
$smtpinfo["host"] = "YOURSITEMAILSERVER.whatever";
$smtpinfo["port"] = "25";
$smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
$smtpinfo["username"] = "Emailaddress@YOURSITEMAILSERVER.whatever";
$smtpinfo["password"] = EMAIL_PASSWORD";
/* Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method */
$mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
/* Ok send mail */
$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $mailmsg);
```

Comment: in this way a copy will sent to $bcc as Bcc but if I want to send email as Cc then how I will do that.